# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).amazingslider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, slider, lightbox

I've created a video lightbox slider using amazing slider javascript, and the code is working fine on local, but as I'm implementing it on my template then a very strange error occurs. however, all the required CDN is added

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).amazingslider is not a function
```

[image]

Here is the complete code which I'm using

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://amazingslider.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.5.1' id='jquery-core-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingslider/sharedengine/amazingslider.js?ver=4.2' id='amazingslider-script-js'></script>
<script src="https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingslider/19/sliderengine/initslider.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .demo-slider-3 {
        margin: 0em auto 8em;
        max-width: 600px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .amazingslider-bottom-shadow-0 {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>

<div class="demo-slider-3">
    <div id="amazingslider-19" style="display:block;position:relative;margin:15px auto 30px;">
        <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">

            <li>
                <a href="#videolink" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="#imagelink"/>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#videolink" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="#imagelink"/>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#videolink" class="html5lightbox">
                    <img src="#imagelink"/>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="amazingslider-thumbnails" style="display:none;">
            <li><img src="#imagelink"/></li>
            <li><img src="#imagelink"/></li>
            <li><img src="#imagelink"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "implementing it on my template"? Can you add code for that?

Comment: My template is a website page where I have created it using dynamic content images and videos are added from the backend instead of direct urls

Comment: The error is showing in this file initslider.js

Comment: The error is simply saying that perhaps `amazingslider.js` (second script) failed to load. Please check if you are getting any network errors

Comment: All files are loading and there is no network errors

Comment: Open you website page and then in the JS console, run `jQuery.fn.amazingslider`. Do you get any output or is it `undefined`?

Comment: Yes getting undefined after running this code on console

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function insertToHead(src) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', src);
    head.appendChild(script);
  };
  var jQueryLoaded = setInterval(function(){
    if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined')
    {
      clearInterval(jQueryLoaded);
      insertToHead('http://yourwebsite.com/myslider/amazingslider.js');
    }
  }, 500);
  var AmazingSliderLoaded = setInterval(function(){
    if ((typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') && jQuery.fn.amazingslider)
    {
      clearInterval(AmazingSliderLoaded);
      insertToHead('http://yourwebsite.com/myslider/initslider-1.js');
    }
  }, 500);
</script>
```

By using this script I'm able to run it on my website